# Self-encrypting NVME drive recommendations?

Tags: encryption, ssd

We work with sensitive data.  We *must* have encryption, and performance is a primary consideration.  We'd really like to allow the developers to have their choice of working in Windows or Linux.

I'm a little concerned by the articles floating around saying that Samsung and Crucial have drives whose FDE firmware is trivial to compromise.  We'd much rather not do it all in software, if we can avoid it.

Price is a concern.  Are there any non-enterprise NVME drives that:

- support self-encryption, and
- have good onboard encryption acceleration, and
- of key importance, **work with an Ubuntu package for encryption management** -- I'm mostly thinking about managing recovery keys, but there may be other features that I haven't thought about